# Design pattern with prolog and epilog

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I'm searching for design patter that could implement some prolog code and then epilog code.
Let me explain:

I have an function (a lot of them) that amost do the same thing:

this is presudo code but actually it's written in C# 4.5

```
public IDatabaseError GetUserByName(string Name)
{
  try
  {
      //Initialize session to database
  }
  catch (Exception)
  {
     // return error with description for this step
  }

  try
  {
       // Try to create 'transaction' object
  }
  catch(Exception)
  {
     // return error with description about this step
  }

  try
  {       
      // Execute call to database with session and transaction object
      //
      // Actually in all function only this section of the code is different
      //
  }
  catch(Exception)
  {
      // Transaction object rollback
      // Return error with description for this step
  }
  finally
  {
      // Close session to database
  }

   return everything-is-ok  
}
```

So - as you can see 'prolog' (Create session, transaction, other helper function) and 'epilog' (close session, rollback transaction, clean memeory, etc..) is the same for **all** functions.

Some restrictions:

- I want to keep session and transaction object creation/destruction process **in** function and not in ctor
- Custom code (that running in the middle) must be wrapped in try/catch and return different error for different situation
- I'm open for any Func<>, Action<> preferable Task<> functions suggestions

  Any ideas for design patter or code refactoring ?

Comment: BTW I don't think returning an error instead of throwing an exception is a nice idea.

Comment: Take a look at the Decorator pattern

Comment: Jasper: Returning anything in case of exception is an antidesign pattern and you shouldn't do it at all!

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved by using IDisposable objects as for example:

```
using(var uow = new UnitOfWork() )
using(var t = new TransactionScope() )
{
   //query the database and throws exceptions
   // in case of errors
}
```

Please nothe the [TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) class is an out-of-the box class you have in System.Transaction that works ( not only ) with DB connections.
In the UnitOfWork `constructor` do the "Prologue" code ( ie open the connection... ), in the `Dispose` do the epilogue part. By throwing exception when error occours you are sure the epilogue part is called anyway.

Comment: So - let's say exception happens in UnitOfWork() class - how I gonna return 'IDatabaseError' object ? In 'using' statements you using constructor of the object that does not return any state-object, only construct/initialize it....

Comment: @Jasper as I said I don't think is a good idea returning something in case of exception. But if you can't change, wrap the code with a try/catch and return the error in the catch part.

Comment: Felice Pollano: I understand. So any ideas for pattern that **doesn't** throw Exception ?

Comment: +1: Was going to suggest the same thing. Creating a custom IDisposable class or struct is a great way to execute before/after code in a block, and guarantee execution always. I've used this in many high performance systems to provide nested suspend/resume around a block of code

Comment: Whoever +1 this answer - what about my question in the first comment ? Any answer for this ? if you think that @FelicePollano answer is correct.

Comment: @Jasper my first reply to your first comment isn't enough ?

Comment: @FelicePollano here is the code:

try
{
using(var uow = new UnitOfWork() )
using(var t = new TransactionScope() )
{
   //query the database and throws exceptions
   // in case of errors
}
catch (Exception)
{
   // who throw me ???
}

Comment: @jasper since you want to return an IDatabaseError ( not the correct pattern IMHO ) create it in the exception handler and return it

Comment: @MattDavey nice work. I used something similar with SqlAdapter like in this example: http://weblogs.asp.net/jasonsalas/archive/2005/02/08/368811.aspx  <- so you see - it's not new

Comment: @FelicePollano you suggesting throwing from constructor ? Like here:

    class UnitOfWork
    {
        public UnitOfWork()
        { throw (new Notimplemented();}

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're looking for the [Template Method Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

The template method pattern will allow you to reduce the amount of duplicated code in similar methods by extracting out only the parts of the method which are different.

For this particular example, you could write a method that does all the grunt work, and then invokes a callback to do the interesting work...

```
// THIS PART ONLY WRITTEN ONCE
public class Database
{
    // This is the template method - it only needs to be written once, so the prolog and epilog only exist in this method...
    public static IDatabaseError ExecuteQuery(Action<ISession> queryCallback)
    {

        try
        {
            //Initialize session to database
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // return error with description for this step
        }

        try
        {
            // Try to create 'transaction' object
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            // return error with description about this step
        }

        try
        {       
            // Execute call to database with session and transaction object
            //
            // Actually in all function only this section of the code is different
            //
            var session = the session which was set up at the start of this method...

            queryCallback(session);
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            // Transaction object rollback
            // Return error with description for this step
        }
        finally
        {
            // Close session to database
        }

        return everything-is-ok
    }
}
```

This is the usage:

```
// THIS PART WRITTEN MANY TIMES
IDatabaseError error = Database.ExecuteQuery(session =>
{
    // do your unique thing with the database here - no need to write the prolog / epilog...

    // you can use the session variable - it was set up by the template method...

    // you can throw an exception, it will be converted to IDatabaseError by the template method...
});

if (error != null)
    // something bad happened!
```

I hope I have explained better this time :)

Comment: Well, thats not true. Template method pattern gives you variability, not "less code" - the latter is a nice side effect at best.

Comment: You're correct it's not the main purpose of the pattern however I still think it's appropriate in this case.

Comment: That's true. Simpler than AOP, too. +1

Comment: I don't know who give this answer +1 -> this is not what I'm looking for. @MattDavey just separate some code from big gigantic function - I'm not seeing big (!) difference from my code. This is not what I'm looking for. Still - the prolog and epilog code is not generic for **any** function - it just some of the code will run in 'GetUserByNameImpl' function.

Comment: @Jasper you've completely misunderstood what I was trying to say. And given that you were fairly rude about it, I'm not inclined to provide further explanation. Please do not downvote people who are trying to help you.

Comment: @MattDavey - Sorry. Didn't mean to hurt you. You just +1 your own answer that I intentionally leave blank.. Sorry again

Comment: @Jasper it is not possible to +1 your own answer on StackOverflow, only other people can +1.

Comment: @Jasper I have re-written my code example above, I hope you can see that I am trying to help :)

Comment: @Jasper downvoting in your own question is kind of a faux pas and a good way to make sure that people don't help you.

Comment: @Yaur: 1) I don't really know why people +1 those answers without any reason - just because it's some fancy code ? 2) All those answers is falling in category: been-there-done-that. It's not the answers/help I'm looking for. Sorry if it's look like I downvoting the answers but please try to understand: I see what you talking about - this is not what I need

Comment: @Jasper please review http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down. All of the answers you have down voted here are solid methods to solve your problem and none of them fall in categories outlined there.  Further complicating the matter is that what you think you need seems to be different than what you actually need.